# How do I get the current script or class name in Scala?

Tags: class, scala, filenames

I'd like my Scala program to be able to programmatically determine either its script filename or its class name, store the string in a variable `program` and print out the name.

Java has [several](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptName#Java) methods for this.

Comment: Have you tried adopting the Java solutions you mention? Looks like they should all work (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// With help from huynhjl
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129185#8131613

import scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator

object ScriptName {
    val program = {
        val filenames = new RuntimeException("").getStackTrace.map { t => t.getFileName }
        val scala = filenames.indexOf("NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java")

        if (scala == -1)
            "<console>"
        else
            filenames(scala - 1)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val prog = program
        println("Program: " + prog)
    }
}
```

[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Program_name#Scala)

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the simplest:

```
val program = new Exception().getStackTrace.head.getFileName
```

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the stack trace as hinted by 0__ should take care of most of the use cases, in particular when the object with the main method is not in a file of the same name:

```
package utils

trait ProgramInfo {
  val programInfo = try { 
    throw new RuntimeException("x")
  } catch { 
    case e: RuntimeException =>
      val arr = new java.io.CharArrayWriter()
      val buffer = new java.io.PrintWriter(arr)
      e.printStackTrace(buffer)
      val trace = arr.toString 
      val lines = io.Source.fromString(trace)
      val pat = """^.*at.*\.main\(([^:]*)(:.*)?\).*$""".r
      lines.getLines().collectFirst{case pat(n, l) => n}.getOrElse("<none>")
  }
}

object ProgramInfo extends ProgramInfo
```

Then you call this like that:

```
println(utils.ProgramInfo.programInfo)
```

or you mix in into your main object

```
object A extends utils.ProgramInfo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     println(programInfo)
   }
}
```

This works for scripts `scala A.script` whether the code is wrapped in an object or not. This also works when compiled with `scalac` and run as `scala A`. When run with the REPL, this will return `<none>`.

Comment: That _almost_ works. When I run it, it prints empty parentheses `()`.

Comment: @mcandre, odd. I guess add a `println(trace)` after the `val trace` definition and see if `.main(xxx)` appears anywhere.

Comment: Ah, the problem was my scribe error. I tried writing a function `def` to return the program name, but Scala treats `def`s as void functions. The more you know.

Comment: Also, Scala borks on the `package` statement.

Comment: @mcandre, Oh yeah package only works with compiled code not with the REPL.

Comment: Any idea why? It's annoying how shebangs work with the interpreter but not the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for...

```
$ scala -e 'println( "I am " + getClass.getName )'
```

gives me

```
"I am Main$$anon$1"
```

And

```
$ scala -e 'try { sys.error( "" )} catch { case e => println( "I am " + e.getStackTrace()( 3 ))}'
```

gives me

```
"I am Main.main(scalacmd2873893687624153305.scala)"
```

Comment: For example, if we have a program Hello.scala, I want to programmatically detect within Hello#main that the class name is "Hello", save that to a variable `program`, and print it out.

Comment: @mcandre In Scala, you don't run a main method from within a class - you run it in an object. If you are calling from a class instance, the above `getClass.getName` will work. (It will also work in an object, but might not look quite how you expect.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec scala "$0" "$0" "$@"
!#

val program = args(0)
println(program)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code snippet. Could you write it so that it also compiles well with `scalac`?