# getting script filename and printing it

Tags: scala

I'm wondering if there is some way to get the scripts file name programatically and print it to the console, eg in php it's SCRIPT_NAME in batch it's %0 in some other languages it's arg[0]

without writing some complex routines is this possible in scala or is it so limited?

Comment: Try looking at the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129185/how-do-i-get-the-current-script-or-class-name-in-scala

Comment: i already had, that doesn't answer my question they are telling him how to get the class name not the file name that could change at any time by a user.

Comment: and the one that is marked as the correct answer just gives me <console>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're executing a scala script using `scala <scriptname>` you can get the name as follows:

```
//Filename: temp.scala
println("Hello there")  //valid statment
val name=System.getProperty("sun.java.command").split(" ")(1)
println("name: " + name)
```

Gives me the output:

```
C:\Users\plastygrove\Desktop\tmp>scala temp.scala
Hello there
name: temp.scala
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention, code is from this post: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptName#Java as pointed to in this post: [How do I get the current script or class name in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8129185/1287554)