# Scala args(0) Reason

Tags: scala

Please understand that I have no Java background and this is my first hour using Scala. I am *not* bashing Scala - just curious about the design decisions.

Was there a reason why Scala decided to flaunt convention in regard to its **args** object?

In comparison with the languages that I am familiar with, I would have expected the Scala args(0) to return the name of the executable and args(1) to return the first argument.

Instead of utilizing the above 'unspoken' convention, Scala requires the coder to mix in some Java code just to get the executable's name (re. [getting script filename and printing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349571/getting-script-filename-and-printing-it)).

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/flaunt-or-flout

Comment: Thank you for your grammar lesson. As your reference indicates, its a common error...

Comment: So common that maybe it will just become usage. (That is, disobedience or disregard is the real shared element.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way Java does it and Scala just follows along, since both are compiled to JVM bytecode and run in the same way. (e.g. `java -jar myjar.jar)`

So the reason is the same as Java's: you can read a discussion about it here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/211073/why-does-java-not-put-the-filename-in-args.

In short, the concept of passing the filename is less meaningful in Java/Scala than in C/C++ and you can easily get it anyway in case you need it.

Comment: Let's also not forget that Java and Scala can run on platforms that don't even have files and thus a concept of "filename" at all.