# Getting command and arguments as String in Scala

Tags: scala

A small program that can be packed as a jar and you run it in the console like this:

```
scala program.jar -v --debug --file "/home/user/..."
```

Is there a way to get the whole command with all the parameters as a String?

```
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("???")  
        // should print: "scala program.jar -v --debug --file "/home/user/..."
    }    
}
```

Comment: use `"scala program.jar " + args.mkString(" ")`. You already know that first commands will always be `scala program.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reliably get the complete command line (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314687/scala-args0-reason)) but you can get close.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val allargs = "scala" +: System.getProperty("sun.java.command").split(" ").tail
    println(allargs.mkString(" "))
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mkstring` method of array. As argument you can place separator between array entities.

Ex: http://ideone.com/

```
val argss = Array("a", "b", "c --d")
println(argss.mkString(" "))
```